# How to retrieve to Radio button group in android studio with SQL-lite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-fragments

I have tried to retrieve data to a radio button group. Data insertion is ok but I want some help, for retrieving the data to the radiobutton Group.

```
 }
                else{
                    while(res.moveToNext()){
                        Log.d(res.getString(2),"id");
                        dob_et.setText(res.getString(2));
                        Gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId(res.getString(3));
                        pw_et.setText(res.getString(4));
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: Radio button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give enough code to answer this exactly but it looks like you are trying to store and restore using the `R.id.` int values? and I don't think is is a good idea as they might change in the future.

You also seem to trying to pass `getCheckedRadioButtonId` a parameter when this method takes none.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId()

There are two ways to set a value in a RadioGroup (I'm having to assume the id's of the RadioButtons and RadioGroup)

1) Indirectly

```java
RadioGroup gender = findViewById(R.id.gender);
gender.check(R.id.male);
```

1) directly

```java
RadioButton male = findViewById(R.id.male);
male.setChecked(true);
```

So restoring the value from the database code would look something like

```java
while(res.moveToNext()){
    String gender = res.getString(3)
    if (gender == "male") {
        RadioButton male = findViewById(R.id.male);
        male.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        RadioButton female = findViewById(R.id.female);
        female.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

PS if you are politically correct now you might have 3 RadioButtons of "Male", "Female" or "Other"